# Is Windows Firewall with Advanced Security available for Windows XP / Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, firewall

Is Windows Firewall with Advanced Security available for Windows XP / Windows Server 2003?
If yes, what is the download link, or how do I add it on?

Comment: Note: "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security" is an MMC snap-in. The firewall is whatever firewall is part of the OS. Some of the policy settings for the XP firewall may be the same as the policy settings for the Win7 firewall -- the IPSEC policy settings controlled by WFAS seem to be different, which implies that some of the other policy settings may be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afraid it's not available for them.

[From the download link](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=19192)

> System requirements
> Supported Operating Systems: Windows 7, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Vista